# Laravel 7 upgrade failing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I was following the Laravel 6.x to Laravel 7.x upgrade doc and made the necessary changes. But it is failing and showing the following error. At the time of running `composer update` there were not 3rd party packages. Then i installed some other packages and after that tried to update again and stuck at this error.

```
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Process\Process::__construct() must be of the type array, string given, called in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Util/ProcessExecutor.php on line 65 and defined in /var/www/html/laravel/laravel-starter/vendor/symfony/process/Process.php:140
Stack trace:
#0 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Util/ProcessExecutor.php(65): Symfony\Component\Process\Process->__construct(''/usr/bin/php7....', NULL, NULL, NULL, 300)
#1 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(245): Composer\Util\ProcessExecutor->execute(''/usr/bin/php7....')
#2 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(96): Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch(Object(Composer\Script\Event))
#3 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Autoload/AutoloadGenerator.php(312): Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatchScript('post-autoload-d...', true, Array, Array)
#4 phar:///usr/local/bin in /var/www/html/laravel/laravel-starter/vendor/symfony/process/Process.php on line 140

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Process\Process::__construct() must be of the type array, string given, called in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Util/ProcessExecutor.php on line 65 and defined in /var/www/html/laravel/laravel-starter/vendor/symfony/process/Process.php:140
Stack trace:
#0 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Util/ProcessExecutor.php(65): Symfony\Component\Process\Process->__construct(''/usr/bin/php7....', NULL, NULL, NULL, 300)
#1 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(245): Composer\Util\ProcessExecutor->execute(''/usr/bin/php7....')
#2 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(96): Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch(Object(Composer\Script\Event))
#3 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Autoload/AutoloadGenerator.php(312): Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatchScript('post-autoload-d...', true, Array, Array)
#4 phar:///usr/local/bin in /var/www/html/laravel/laravel-starter/vendor/symfony/process/Process.php on line 140
```

Source of the project is available at: https://github.com/nasirkhan/laravel-starter/tree/v7

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all of your symfony dependencies are at least 5.0 and that your composer is updated by running `composer self-update`.

Comment: thanks. I did the same and just found that i updated the global version and running the local version of the composer. 
the update done.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel 7 upgraded Symfony from 4 to 5 and `Process` syntax changed:

Before:

```
$process = new Process('ls -l');
```

After:

```
$process = new Process(array('ls', '-l'));
```

You need to adjust your code to the new syntax.

More info here: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.x/UPGRADE-5.0.md#process